# How to build Xamarin.Mac app on Azure pipelines

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, xamarin.mac

Azure pipelines has [tasks that support building Xamarin apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xamarin?view=azure-devops) for iOS and Android.  For iOS this includes the optional capability to package a .ipa file that is suitable for upload to the store.

For my project I'm building a macOS app with Xamarin.Mac and looking to be able to automate the build in Azure pipelines, but get stuck at the packaging step.  Using an [msbuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=azure-devops) invocation I can have the .app built and signed in the pipeline just fine.

The next step in the VisualStudio GUI would be clicking "Build->Archive for Publishing", which produces a .xcarchive file (not entirely sure what this is?  Just a zip maybe?), then you can click "Sign and Distribute" to go through a wizard that will produce the .pkg file for submission to the store.

This part is what I can't find a way to do in the pipeline.  Is there a manual command line way to build the signed .pkg file in lieu of direct support for Xamarin.Mac?

**EDIT:** I found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/create-xcarchive), but adding the "/p:ArchiveOnBuild=true" argument to my msbuild invocation still has not produced an xcarchive file.  The docs seem to indicate that it should, so I'm at a loss there.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but never the less; I have just spent most of a day struggling with the same problem.

I found this excellent blog-post helping a bunch
https://witekio.com/blog/xamarin-mac-on-azure-devops/

The idea is basically to build on MacOS and use bash instead of Powershell

I ended up with the following pipeline:

```
    trigger:
    - master
    
    variables:
      #app data
      outputAppName: '<Name of outputtet app without .app>'
      projectName: '<Name of your project>'
    
      #keys and accounts
      azureSubscription: <Azure subscription for publishing result>
      storageAccountKey: <storage account key>
      storageAccountName: <storage account name>
      storageContainerName: <storage container name>
     
# Working Directory
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(projectName)'
  configuration: 'Release'
  outputArtifactPath: '$(workingDirectory)/$(projectName)/bin/$(configuration)/$(outputAppName).app'
 
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'macos-latest'

  

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    
      - checkout: self  # self represents the repo where the initial Pipelines YAML file was found
        displayName: Check out 
        clean: true
        #lfs: false  # whether to download Git-LFS files
        submodules: true   # set to 'true' for a single level of submodules or 'recursive' to get submodules of submodules
        persistCredentials: true  
        path: htpaa_backend_shared_util
        condition: 

      - task: Bash@3
        displayName: 'Change Mono version'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            SYMLINK=6_4_0
            MONOPREFIX=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/$SYMLINK
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH;]$MONOPREFIX/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_PATH"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PKG_CONFIG_PATH;]$MONOPREFIX/lib/pkgconfig:$MONOPREFIX/share/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]$MONOPREFIX/bin:$PATH"

      - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
        displayName: 'Use NuGet'

      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        displayName: 'NuGet restore'
        inputs:
          restoreSolution: '$(workingDirectory)/*.sln'
    
      - task: MSBuild@1
        inputs:
          solution: '$(workingDirectory)/*.sln'
          platform: 'Any CPU'
          configuration: '$(configuration)'
          restoreNugetPackages: true
      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: '$(outputArtifactPath)'
          includeRootFolder: true
          archiveType: 'zip'
          archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)_$(projectName).zip'
          replaceExistingArchive: true
          verbose: true
          
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: 'CLI Copy files to Azure Storage'
        inputs:
            azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
            scriptType: ps
            scriptLocation: inlineScript
            inlineScript: |
             az storage blob upload --account-name $(storageAccountName) --container-name $(storageContainerName) --name '$(Build.BuildId)_$(projectName).zip' --file '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)_$(projectName).zip'  --account-name $(storageAccountName) --account-key $(storageAccountKey)
```